Receiving STOMP protocol messages through session IDs does not work with Postman or APIC sites
I want to use tools like APIC or Postman to send messages using the STOMP protocol and then, on my local server, identify the session ID of the sender of the message and send a response back to that specific session.
I've verified the session ID and sent a message to that session, but the message isn't being received. I wonder if using testing tools like APIC or Postman could be causing this issue, even if the session ID is correct.
Do I need to test this locally? I'm curious about the potential reasons why the message might not be received.
@MessageMapping("/chat")
public void handleChatMessage(Message<?> message, ChatRequest chatRequest) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

    Long chatRoomId = chatRequest.chatRoomId();
    Long userId = (Long) accessor.getSessionAttributes().get("userId");
    String sessionId = accessor.getSessionId();

    // When a user sends a message to enter the chat room (frontend is subscribed to "/user/queue/reply")
    if (chatRequest.messageType().equals(ChatRequest.MessageType.ENTER)) {
        log.info("ENTER message, chatRequest: {}", chatRequest);
        ChatResponse chatResponse = handleEnterMessage(chatRequest, userId);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/reply", chatResponse, createHeaders(sessionId));
        log.info("Message sent to /user/queue/reply for session: {}", sessionId);
    }
}

private MessageHeaders createHeaders(String sessionId) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    return headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders();
}



Is it generally not possible to perform WebSocket communication using session IDs with tools like Postman or APIC?
